# Javascript Objects cross referencing each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, pass-by-reference, javascript-objects, factory

I'm trying to develop a plugin for [router5](http://router5.github.io/).

A router5 plugin is a function taking a router instance and returning an object with a name and some methods.

You can find the relevant part of the code below:

```
function myPluginFactory(store) {
  // So that store can be in the closure
  function myPlugin(router){

    // The router will reference the store
    router.setDependency({'store': store});

    // The store will reference the router
    store.setRouter(router);

    // Public APi
    return {
      onTransitionStart(fromState, toState){
        router.onTransitionStart(fromState, toState);
      }
      // ...
    }
  }

  myPlugin.pluginName = "MY_PLUGIN";
  return myPlugin;
}

class RouterStore {
  router = null;

  setRouter(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
}


// **************** //

import routes from './routes';
import createRouter from 'router5';

const myRouterStore = new RouterStore();
const router = createRouter(routes, {});

// The .usePlugin will call the function returned by 
// myPluginFactory(myRouterStore) and call it passing the router instance
router.usePlugin(myPluginFactory(myRouterStore));
```

So first I instantiate my router, then I call the method usePlugin to create and pass my plugin to the router.

My **problem** comes from the first 2 instruction of the myPlugin function.
That is:

- I create  reference from the router object to the store object
- Create a reference from the store object to the router object

**This creates a cross referencing.**

**Question:**
Does this cross-reference create problems in javascript? May I fall in some sort of circular call and break the universe?
Is this a ugly pattern and should be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use this pattern. Cross referencing used to implement trees and graps in js and it's very common.
But it could lead to memory leaks, since js objects get garbage collected only if there is no references to them. (In your example not likely)
Altho in nested iterations by properties ti cold create an infinite cycle.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the pattern.

Garbage collectors will occasionally follow every reference there is, beginning from the root (global scope). This means that inaccessible circular references will get garbage collected.

You shouldn't worry about these stuff. The whole idea of a garbage collector is to take that responsibility away from you.